Add gridlines and y=x line to seaborn lmplot
I have the following code below to plot a regression plot with respect to categorical variables. The variable of interest in this question is "Site".
children_with_PNC_plot_site = sns.lmplot(x="Z Score, Post Central WM Right for All Patients vs. All Controls, Ages 6-18", 
                                         y="Z Score, Post Central WM Right for Children Patients vs. All Controls", 
                                         hue = "Site", palette = "hsv", data=df, fit_reg=False) 


Is there a way to add both horizontal and vertical gridlines to the plot below, along with the line y=x?
When I try to do any of the above, I always get a new plot with either the gridlines only, or the y=x line.
Thanks!

sns.lmplot(...) is a "figure-level" function, which creates its own figure, possibly with many subplots.  When there is only one subplot, you can plot on it using the ax of the returned "FacetGrid".
Here is an example:
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
g = sns.lmplot(data=iris, x='sepal_length', y='petal_length', hue='species', fit_reg=False)
g.ax.axline((0, 0), slope=1, color='k', ls='--')
g.ax.grid(True, axis='both', ls=':')


If you create multiple subplots (e.g. via the col= parameter), you can loop through all the subplots:
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
g = sns.lmplot(data=iris, x='sepal_length', y='petal_length', col='species', fit_reg=False)
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.axline((0, 0), slope=1, color='k', ls='--')
    ax.grid(True, axis='both', ls=':')



Seaborn a superset to the matplotlib library that adds new styles, plots and functionalities to different degrees. The plot that you chose lmplot returns a FacetGrid object which is a Seaborn figure level object which is not easily extensible. The straight forward solution would be to use it as intended which is by running it in a context such as a Jupyter cell, similar to matplotlib's "plt". The following will work (just removing the variable assignement):
import seaborn as sns

x_label = "Z Score, Post Central WM Right for All Patients vs. All Controls, Ages 6-18"
y_label = "Z Score, Post Central WM Right for Children Patients vs. All Controls"

sns.lmplot(
    x=x_label, 
    y=y_label, 
    hue="Site",
    palette="hsv",
    data=df,
    fit_reg=False
) 

xy_min = min(df[x_label].min(), df[y_label].min())
xy_max = max(df[x_label].max(), df[y_label].max())

sns.lineplot(
    x=[xy_min, xy_max],
    y=[xy_min, xy_max],
    color='grey',
    linestyle='--',
    legend=None
)

sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

However, if you wish to use the object syntax (which I also favour) you can switch the lmplot for a simple scatter, since it seems you are not taking advantage of any special functionality from it, and then make it compatible with matplotlib container objects and syntax. This will get the same result:
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x_label = "Z Score, Post Central WM Right for All Patients vs. All Controls, Ages 6-18"
y_label = "Z Score, Post Central WM Right for Children Patients vs. All Controls"

sns.scatterplot(
    x=x_label, 
    y=y_label, 
    hue="Site",
    palette="hsv",
    data=df,
    ax=ax
)

xy_min = min(df[x_label].min(), df[y_label].min())
xy_max = max(df[x_label].max(), df[y_label].max())

sns.lineplot(
    x=[xy_min, xy_max],
    y=[xy_min, xy_max],
    color='grey',
    linestyle='--',
    legend=None,
    ax=ax
)

ax.grid()
ax.legend(loc='right')


fig

Now you have the power of matplotlib subplots and the style of seaborn (with hues and palletes) in a single plot. You can break down and run your second snippet of code on different cells, and pass the fig and ax object to functions to manipulate them which is quite convenient. The final result will look like this:


this fails if min and max of x and y are not adhering to x=y. Which is the case here

Thank you for your contribution you are absolutely right. Taking the min and the max between the axis should do the trick. Now the x=y line should be right.

nice implementation!

It is now correct thanks to you.

In the end these kinds of answers are a matter of preferences, there are too many ways to achieve the same result with these plotting libraries. I love Seaborn stylings but I find matplotlib subplots are extremely useful and flexible so I tend to combine them all the time since seaborn allow seemless integration.

it's a cool question, though a duplicate

I feel like the question is not really duplicated at least in reference to one marked as being a duplicate from. (I don't know it is a duplicate of any others or a mix of them). First, this question deals with seaborn while the other uses matplotlib (similar but different libraries), then there is the issue of the lmplot which returns a FacetGrid object not compatible with regular methods, and last is the combination of matplotlib and seaborn to get reliable solution. Probably the pieces are all scattered in many answers but IMO there is novelty in combining them into a cohesive answer.

seaborn uses matplotlib underneath, the best thing to do would be to just use ax.axline((0, 0), slope=1) after plotting with seaborn
